# Using a wild card in Gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, gremlinpython

I have two queries:

```
g.V().has("kind", "some_value").toList()
```

and

```
g.V().has("kind").toList()
```

and each one is invoked depending if I got `kind` value, so the method looks like this:

```
def query(kind=None):
    if not kind:
        return g.V().has("kind").toList()
    else:
        return g.V().has("kind", kind).toList()
```

I was wondering if I could unify if into a single query using a wild card, something like the following code

```
def query(kind='*'):
    return g.V().has("kind", kind).toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the air-routes data set as an example you can do something like this:

```
 g.inject('AUS').as('a').
   V().choose(select('a'),
              where(eq('a')).by('code').by(),
              has('code'))

==>v[3]
```

In this case `code` would be like `kind` in your example. If `a` is not defined then the else part of the `choose` will be executed.